# Webassembly growing memory and importing malloc

Tags: webassembly

After reading the specifications I was trying to grow some memory and did the following:

```
(module
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (export "f" (func $0))
  (func $0 (param $0 i32) (result i32)
    get_local $0
    grow_memory
  )
)
```

Now I was hoping that if we input 10 that we have a page size multiple of 11, so something like:

```
 (memory $0 1)
```

Becomes

```
 (memory $0 11)
```

I had to add a return value since the stack wasnt emptied. Now I assume that the method returns something other than -1 if it succeeds right? In this case I think it works and I should have more pages.

I know there is also the JS way but I prefer doing all this stuff directly inside WebAssembly. Interesting though is the fact that we can import C functions such as malloc, free, strcopy etc from "Env"..

So my question is: is my approach for growing the memory correct? Should I import the C style modules instead? What is the relation between grow_memory and realloc(), or say the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grow_memory` returns the previous size (in pages) or `-1` [according to its specification](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Semantics.md#resizing).

This doesn't change the initial page allocation `(memory $0 1)`! That's a static property of the module, whereas current memory size is a dynamic property of the memory. It's like growing an array which you initially reserved 1 element for. You still initially reserved 1, what's changed is the current size.

You could also use `drop` to ignore the return value of `grow_memory`.

`malloc` / `free` / `realloc` are all things you can implement using `grow_memory`. That opcode is similar to [`sbrk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sbrk). Of course, the WebAssembly embedder also uses memory allocation to grant your opcode's request, which may itself be implemented with `malloc` / `free` / `realloc`, or more likely with `mmap`.

Comment: Wow nice, you are right. Also drop is nice, I totally forgot about it. Really helpful for keeping the stack clear when neccesary.

Comment: I could also discard the information according to https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/FutureFeatures.md#finer-grained-control-over-memory. The selected range is just zeroed out. Interesting.

Comment: One question, so did I understand correctly that grow_memory is used under the hood then using malloc etc ?

Comment: That's a tool which WebAssembly gives to your toolchain. It doesn't have to use that tool. Emscripten can be used like asm.js and not use `grow_memory`: just pre-allocate a large enough memory and hope you never need more. Then its malloc implementation simply has to allocate within that memory, but can't ever get more. It can also use `grow_memory` if you want, but WebAssembly doesn't force you either way. You can even write valid (and useful!) WebAssembly modules without any memory.